# Adding tables from 1 MSSQL database to the other

Tags: sql-server

Here are college, every single student gets an MSSQL database. Because we have several thousand student however, user-rights are restricted. You get 1 database, and only one.

If you're making multiple ASP.NET website, you just put the new tables in the same database. That's how it is and it's not going to change.

Now, I work on a home computer as well, with my local database to make things easy. Most sites had 2 or 3 tables with a couple of entries, so making them again on the school database I have and entering the data again isn't a lot of work.

This time however, our assignment involves the NorthWind Database, an example database that Microsoft has up for download, for everyone to use.

I'm looking for a way to tell my school database to add the tables from the Northwind database, in to its own database. I'm using mssql management studio 2008 r2. I've been looking around a bit but haven't found anything. Is this at all possible?

Also, deleting tables from the school database doesn't seem to work. Always getting an error that says there are foreign keys so it can't be deleted. Selecting all tables and trying to delete them all at once doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove objects that are referenced.

To copy table *structure* to a different database, script the CREATE TABLE statements to a .sql script file, and run that on the target database.

To copy table *data* to a different database, use the **bcp** utility to generate exports on the source server, and use BULK INSERT on the target server to load these files.

SQL Books Online (BOL) contains details for these procedures.